# Errors in SQL developper with folder

Tags: sql, oracle

I have create a folder with sql developer like the command "create or replace folder...." MY_DIR is the name of my folder.
My error it's in the line 21 this line : "l_fichier_log  := utl_file.fopen( w_repertoire, w_fichier, 'w');"

```
create or replace PROCEDURE JSP

AS

   CURSOR C_donnees IS
      select distinct CODPRO, MOTCLE,CODZN6,CODZN8
      From PRO WHERE CODZN6 = 'C' AND CODSOC = '1';

   w_sysdate varchar2(20);
   w_repertoire varchar2(64);
   w_fichier varchar2(80);
   l_fichier_log      utl_file.file_type;

BEGIN

   SELECT To_Char(SysDate, 'YYYYMMDD_HH24MISS') DATEJOUR INTO w_sysdate FROM Dual;

   w_repertoire := 'MY_DIR';
   w_fichier := 'extraction_'||w_sysdate||'.csv';
   dbms_output.put_line('D‚but de la boucle');
   l_fichier_log  := utl_file.fopen( w_repertoire, w_fichier, 'w');
   
   FOR r_donnees IN c_donnees
   LOOP
      utl_file.put_line(l_fichier_log, r_donnees.CODPRO || ';' || r_donnees.MOTCLE    || ';' || r_donnees.CODZN6 || ';' || r_donnees.CODZN8 );
   END LOOP;

   UTL_FILE.fclose_all;
   dbms_output.put_line('FIN du script');
   
END;
```

And the error is :

```
ORA-29283: opération non valide sur le fichier
ORA-06512: à "SYS.UTL_FILE", ligne 536
ORA-29283: opération non valide sur le fichier
ORA-06512: à "SYS.UTL_FILE", ligne 41
ORA-06512: à "SYS.UTL_FILE", ligne 478
ORA-06512: à "C##JLECAT.JSP", ligne 21
ORA-06512: à ligne 2
```

Can you help me please ?

Thank you !

Comment: There's no `create folders` command. The exact `create` command you used would be very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from creating a directory (not "folder"; it is **directory**, an Oracle object), you should have granted privileges to user who will be using it.

So, connected as SYS (just like when you created that directory), run e.g.

```
grant read, write on directory my_dir to julien;
```

(or whichever username it is).

---

I tested your code; it works properly on my database, with privileges granted to my SCOTT user. I used the DUAL table in cursor as I don't have yours.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE jsp
  2  AS
  3     CURSOR c_donnees IS SELECT dummy FROM DUAL;
  4
  5     w_sysdate      VARCHAR2 (20);
  6     w_repertoire   VARCHAR2 (64);
  7     w_fichier      VARCHAR2 (80);
  8     l_fichier_log  UTL_FILE.file_type;
  9  BEGIN
 10     SELECT TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDD_HH24MISS') datejour
 11       INTO w_sysdate
 12       FROM DUAL;
 13
 14     w_repertoire := 'MY_DIR';
 15     w_fichier := 'extraction_' || w_sysdate || '.csv';
 16     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('D but de la boucle');
 17     l_fichier_log := UTL_FILE.fopen (w_repertoire, w_fichier, 'w');
 18
 19     FOR r_donnees IN c_donnees
 20     LOOP
 21        UTL_FILE.put_line (l_fichier_log, r_donnees.dummy);
 22     END LOOP;
 23
 24     UTL_FILE.fclose_all;
 25     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('FIN du script');
 26  END;
 27  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> EXEC jsp;
D but de la boucle
FIN du script

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Therefore, you must have done something wrong.

Comment: I have already try this command but it's not  working I always the same error ='(

Comment: I can't tell what you did (or did not do), but - that code works properly and creates the file. Have a look at example I posted in the answer.

Comment: Ok thank you to have test my code ! And I will try to recreate a profile =) Thank you !